# Automatically repair GRUB on Linux?

Tags: bootloader, repair

I managed to blow out GRUB on Ubuntu 14.04. Ubuntu 14.04 is a particular Linux distribution.

There are plenty of software tutorials that attempt to explain how to repair or restore GRBU for Ubuntu. But they always start out, "boot to the Live CD, identify things, ...". For example, [How to Repair, Restore, or Reinstall Grub 2 with a Ubuntu Live CD or USB](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd). However, it requires me to (re-)download a large CD/DVD; and it requires read and understand the manual, which can lead to problems (at times I feel I make more than my share of mistakes :).

All these steps are easily automate-able, and I'd like a prebuilt bootable ISO that simply does it. We kind of have that on Windows (we've had it for years).

For a tool, I would prefer something that automatically boots to a GUI (like GParted). And I would like it to have different versions of GRUB for different distributions (like 1.99 and 2.0).

What tool automatically repairs or restores GRUB for Ubuntu or Linux?

Answer (score 2):

[boot-repair-disk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd) did everything I expected. It had two modes - one was automatic and the other was manual. It also had a GUI, so it was as easy as point and click.

[image: Screenshot] [image: Screenshot] [image: Screenshot]
<sup>*boot-repair* screenshots (source: [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/); click image for larger variant)</sup>

Unfortunately, the problem lies elsewhere (bad VBox Guest Additions manual build), so I think I'm SOL...

Comment: That was the first coming to my mind, too – so I took the freedom to add some screenshots to your answer :)